ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape. Image and mask shape looks correct
I am trying to adapt Tensorflow's example UNet for my purposes. The main difference is this UNet takes 128x128 images and masks and my images are 512x512 and my masks are 100x100.
I am getting this error when I try to run model.fit:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[137], line 2
      1 # %%wandb
----> 2 model_history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=EPOCHS,
      3                           steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
      4                           validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS,
      5                         validation_data=test_dataset,
      6                         callbacks = [ShapeLoggingCallback()])
      7                           #callbacks=[CustomCallback()]) # original: callbacks=[DisplayCallback()])

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.

However, I can run model.predict without issue and it generates a prediction I'd expect from an untrained model.
Here is the code I used to make and train my model:
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=[512, 512, 3], include_top=False)

# Use the activations of these layers
layer_names = [
    'block_1_expand_relu',   # 64x64
    'block_3_expand_relu',   # 32x32
    'block_6_expand_relu',   # 16x16
    'block_13_expand_relu',  # 8x8
    'block_16_project',      # 4x4
]
base_model_outputs = [base_model.get_layer(name).output for name in layer_names]

# Create the feature extraction model
down_stack = tf.keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model_outputs)

down_stack.trainable = False

up_stack = [
    pix2pix.upsample(512, 3),  # 4x4 -> 8x8
    pix2pix.upsample(256, 3),  # 8x8 -> 16x16
    pix2pix.upsample(128, 3),  # 16x16 -> 32x32
    pix2pix.upsample(64, 3),   # 32x32 -> 64x64
]

def unet_model(output_channels:int):
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[512, 512, 3])

    # Downsampling through the model
    skips = down_stack(inputs)
    x = skips[-1]
    skips = reversed(skips[:-1])

    # Upsampling and establishing the skip connections
    for up, skip in zip(up_stack, skips):
        x = up(x)
        concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()
        x = concat([x, skip])

    # This is the last layer of the model
    last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
        filters=output_channels, kernel_size=3, strides=2,
        padding='same')  #64x64 -> 128x128

    x = last(x)

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)

OUTPUT_CLASSES = 5

model = unet_model(output_channels=OUTPUT_CLASSES)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model_history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=EPOCHS,
                        validation_data=test_dataset)

Here is the code I use to create my datasets:
# Get train and validation image paths
train_tiles, train_masks = get_image_paths(train_patient_ids, patient_data)
val_tiles, val_masks = get_image_paths(val_patient_ids, patient_data)
test_tiles, test_masks = get_image_paths(test_patient_ids, patient_data)

def load_image_and_mask(image_path, mask_path):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [512, 512])
    image.set_shape([512, 512, 3])

    mask = tf.io.read_file(mask_path)
    mask = tf.image.decode_png(mask, channels=1) # change channels?
    mask = tf.image.flip_up_down(mask)
    mask = tf.image.resize(mask, [100, 100])
    mask.set_shape([100, 100, 1])

    return image, mask

def process_paths(image_path, mask_path):
    image, mask = tf.py_function(load_image_and_mask, [image_path, mask_path], [tf.float32, tf.float32])
    return image, mask

BATCH_SIZE = 16  # Set the batch size as needed

# train
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_tiles, train_masks))
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(process_paths, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

# val
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((val_tiles, val_masks))
val_dataset = val_dataset.map(process_paths, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

# test
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_tiles, test_masks))
test_dataset = test_dataset.map(process_paths, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)


I tried examining the image shape and mask shape of each batch. The image shape is (16, 512, 512, 3) and the mask shape is (16, 100, 100, 1) for every batch but the last (which only has one image).
I tried putting this code in my process_paths (what the tutorial called it) function:
image = tf.reshape(image, [512, 512, 3])

...
mask = tf.reshape(mask, [100, 100, 1])

I tried playing around with the numbers in up_stack part a bit but ultimately didn't get anywhere because I don't understand that part. My assumption is that, now that I've changed the input size, I have to change the output size of the model's layers, but I'm not really sure how to do that. Also, I am confused why I can still run model.predict if that's the case.
My tensorflow version is 2.16.1

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

@furas done, thank you

Probably an issue with your datasets/whatever you do with the images, might be good to post that as well.

@Anonymous just added, thanks!

I'd try mapping load_image_and_mask directly and ignore process_paths. If that fixes the error, the next issue will likely be the different sizes of your images and masks.
